# Add Httpheader to selenium chrome webdriver in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My C# code looks like this for creating chrome web driver, i wanted to add the custom HTTP headers to all my http requests.

ex: user-agent : Android

```
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"c:\Chrome\");
var option = new ChromeOptions();
_driver = new ChromeDriver(service, option);
```

We have the way for firefox, as the link shows, but for chrome it does not work.
https://eveningsamurai.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/changing-http-headers-for-a-selenium-webdriver-request/

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to handle this case is with FiddlerCore proxy, capture all the requests and modify the header as part of request.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/FiddlerCore/

Nice blog about fiddler core
http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jul/29/Using-FiddlerCore-to-capture-HTTP-Requests-with-NET

```
    public static void Start()
    {
        FiddlerApplication.RequestHeadersAvailable += FiddlerApplication_RequestHeadersAvailable;
        FiddlerApplication.Startup(8888, true, true, true);
    }

    static void FiddlerApplication_RequestHeadersAvailable(Session oSession)
    {
        oSession.RequestHeaders.Add("My_Custom_Header", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    }
```

Comment: Telerik have now unlisted this package from Nuget. The best answer is now the one posted by @guillem

Answer (score 10):

I've been able to manage that using [ModHeaders Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en). Download the plugin CRX file and load it in your test Chrome instance.

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddExtension("WebDrivers/modHeader_2_1_1.crx");

var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Then you can configure the plugin using the local storage as this is where the plugins stores its config too.

```
// set the context to access extension local storage
Configuration.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome-extension://idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/icon.png");

Configuration.driver.ExecuteScript(
    "localStorage.setItem('profiles', JSON.stringify([{                " +
    "  title: 'Selenium', hideComment: true, appendMode: '',           " +
    "  headers: [                                                      " +
    "    {enabled: true, name: 'MY_HEADER', value: 'MY_VALUE', comment: ''}  " +
    "  ],                                                              " +
    "  respHeaders: [],                                                " +
    "  filters: []                                                     " +
    "}]));                                                             ");
```

And finally you can navigate to somewhere and check that the headers are loaded

```
    Configuration.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://example.com/");
```

Comment: I try to do the same in chrome, but cannot get my modheader sending the custom header. Here's the code
https://gist.github.com/cwhsu1984/c15507c4f26433fecca2482fa51aa5a4
Can you provide me some directions to do this?

Comment: To bad, I get this error: `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: <unknown>: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.` (using Chrome)

Comment: Has anyone figured out why the call to ExecuteScript gives this error? "An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll
Additional information: <unknown>: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
  (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.99) occurred"

Comment: The same error OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: '<unknown>: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

Comment: @PhiseySt,  Cause try change the `Navigate().GoToUrl... ExecuteScript...` part to  https://gist.github.com/stevenxi/c4dc7eea563d972dbccd6f7c383dc393  , assuming using latest extension version (4_0_21)