# Need to add Bearer header Authorization to Chrome Run time for Selenium C# when i open Url

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am working on selenium C# where I want to open a URL which requires adding BEarer Token Authorization to be added into Chrome Browser

```
public void openbrowser()
    {     
string url = "https://ago-main-app.azurewebsites.net";
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGci");//Token
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\chromedriver_win32",options); 

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Httpheader to selenium chrome webdriver in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813287/add-httpheader-to-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-c-sharp)